# Filling DataGridview dynamically connected to local SQL database

Tags: c#, gridview, dynamic

I have a project to be done using c# windows forms, in summary, I have Form1, half of it is an MDI container and the other half is spillter with 2 datetimepickers and a button.

What I want is, the user will choose 2 dates from the datetimepickers, then press the ok button and a new form2 will be CREATED dynamically into the MDI container, which means the form2 wasn't created and hidden, it's created during run time. Now the form2 has a gridview which is also created dynamically and connected to my local data base, my problem is when I press the button nothing is displayed on the gridview, only empty columns.
I've tried so many ways but I couldn't find a solution, any help please?

And thats my button click code :

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if (f2.Visible == false)
{

f2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(102, 395);
f2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(401, 348);
f2.Name = "From2";
f2.Text = "KM Driven";
f2.Show();
f2.MdiParent = this;
f2.ControlBox = false;
f2.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
f2.MaximizeBox = false;
f2.ShowIcon = false;
f2.ResumeLayout(false);
f2.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);


this.dataGridView1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)                         ((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top
| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(401, 348);
this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource;
this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode =     System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
this.dataGridView1.Show();

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();


myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", dateTimePicker1.Value);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", dateTimePicker2.Value);
                this.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252TableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252, dateTimePicker1.Value, dateTimePicker2.Value);

this.dataGridView1.Refresh();



this.dataSet1 = new DCS.DataSet1();




}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your data to the binding source as that is the datasource for your grid.

```
this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource.Datasource = this.dataSet1.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252;
```

Comment: thanks for your replay but nothing changed, same result, empty columns :/

Comment: you do also realise you have autogeneratecolumns set to false? so even tho data should now be flowing into rows nothing will display because youve turned their display off. i assumed you had mapped these elsewhere.

Comment: yeah i forgot that autoGenerateColumns, i'v made it to true, now the columns header names appeared but there's no data..